# List of files using webserver side script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, webserver

Require some advice to get me started.
Just trying to do something simple at the moment for learning purposes.

Written a simple html page, with some javascript on a 'client'.

I need a way of getting a file list from my own webserver (including info such as date modified), that I can run from my simple page somehow.

So my question, is javascript + ajax the way I should be approaching this, or is there an easier/better way. Links to tutorials/examples greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write two scripts:

- One that scans a particular directory on webserver and generates results in a format suitable for AJAX (I would recommend JSON format but not JSON-P).
- An AJAX script that queries the script, formats and displays the data.

What server side scripting languages are you familiar with?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Actually I'm not familiar with any, actually hadn't done any web related work before this week. I've only looked at the client side of things and not at all the server side, so I was exactly sure where to start my reading :) From the look of the answers here I'll need to look into how AJAX works on the server side.

Comment: Correction: ... into how AJAX works WITH a php script on the server side!

Comment: I have now written my script in php on the server, which when I run on the server, I can get a list of files, which is close enough for now to what I want to do. Now I just have to work out how to call this script from my client side javascript!

Comment: Does anyone know why I can't run my php script using AJAX from my html page? I am using an ActiveXObject on IE8 with the call object.open("GET", "http://myweb/test/test.php", true); Comes back with a Permission Denied error. Perhaps seems like something to do with this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy, am I approaching this incorrectly?

Comment: Can you post the output generated by your php script? Does it generate HTML, XML, JSON or something else?

Comment: I now no longer get the permission denied which is good. I don't have it on me today, but at the moment I'm just outputting text from my php script within xml tags. Something like <tag>filename1 filename 2</tag> I'm not 100% sure at the moment how to actually get the php output from my client side javascript, but I used the GET function. Will have to play with it again a bit on Monday.

Answer (score 0):

> is javascript + ajax the way I should be approaching this

That would be only part of the solution. You will also need to write a server side script which will return the list of files and then you could query this script using AJAX by passing it the script name yuo would like to get info about. The reason why you might need a server side script is because javascript has no direct access of server files and information like date modified.

Comment: Right that makes sense, I suppose this would be for security reasons. I should also throw in that my eventual use for working this problem out is to run this page on an existing internal network. Small part of a larger quick prototype, this webserver bit is the part I know nothing about, so forgive my silly questions probably soon to come, thanks so far guys :)

Answer (score 0):

HTML and JavaScript run on client side. You need a server side technology to parse the file list on your web server and throw the output in HTML. Some server side technologies are `ASP.NET, PHP, NodeJS` etc.